# my html code appear without any space in some online editors like codepen

Tags: html, css

I'm learning web development through freecodecamp, I finished the HTML and CSS course and I have built some projects, my last project was a product landing page.
this is the URL: https://mus733.github.io/

the code inside: https://github.com/mus733/mus733.github.io

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1000">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
 <header id="header">

     <img id="header-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/afdoxZ5.png" alt="Mercedes Benz Logo">

    <nav id="nav-bar">
       <a href="#middle-content" class="nav-link"> Feature</a> 
        <a href="#Youtube-video" class="nav-link">How it Works </a>
        <a href="#price-container" class="nav-link">Price</a>


    </nav>
    </header>   
    </div> 

    <div id="content">
        <h1>The New S Class , feel the intelligent drive</h1>
        </div>


            <form id="form" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit" >
                <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="enter your email here" name="email">


                <input id="submit"  type="submit">





            </form>
<div class="middle-content" id="middle-content">

    <img class="icon" src="https://imgur.com/yQfRCem.png" alt="icon1">
    <div class="text-align">We have smartphones, so why wouldn’t we expect our cars to have some intelligence themselves? With Mercedes-Benz Intelligent Drive, you’ll have access to a suite of driving assistance systems that always seem to be one step ahead of you.</div>
</div>    

<div class="middle-content">
    <img class="icon" src="https://imgur.com/WXnhs8Q.png" alt="icon2">
    <div class="text-align">Mercedes-Benz COMAND® maps are designed to help you get to your destination by providing clear directions, as well as plenty of advance notice for upcoming turns along the way.</div>
</div>

<div class="middle-content">


    <img class="icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/sdQaxdN.png" alt="icon3">
    <div class="text-align">Mercedes-Benz's signature Pre-Safe technology will help warn drivers whenever there's an imminent accident. This technology will also help prepare the vehicle for the collision by tightening seatbelts, closing the sunroof and windows, and even adjust front head restraints.</div>

</div>


<div id="Youtube-video">
    <iframe id="video" width="646" height="363" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mQLK6c5vOHM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>


<div id="price-container">
    <div id="price-control">

        <div id="price1" class="price-css">
            <div class="shadow"></div>
            <div class="price-text">
                <h1>$104,000</h1>
                <h2>Top-notch interior</h2>
                <h2>Posh, pampering seating </h2>
                <h2>Supremely comfortable ride</h2>

                <button>Select</button>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="price2" class="price-css">
            <div class="shadow"></div>
            <div class="price-text">
                <h1>$200,000</h1>
                <h2>Massaging front seats</h2>
                <h2>Proximity keyless entry</h2>
                <h2>AMG S 65 coupe and cabriolet </h2>
                <button>Select</button>

            </div>

        </div>












    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer-parent">
<footer>

<ul>Privacy</ul>
<ul id="terms">Terms</ul>
<ul>Contact</ul>



</footer>
<div id="copyright">Copyright 2020, Mercedes-Benz</div>

</div>







</body>
</html>
```

also my css :

```
body{

    background-color:#ecf0f1;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: roboto;
    color: #1e272e;


}
h1{
    color:#1e272e ;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 45px;
}
h2{
    color:#1e272e ;
    font-size: 17px;
}

header{

    background-color: #2c3e50;
    height: 80px;
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    color:#ecf0f1 ;
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-color: #4e9ce9;
    border-width: 5px;







}
@media(max-width: 400px){
    #nav-bar{
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}


#nav-bar{
    font-size: 20px;

}

#content{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 100;

}
#submit{
    width: 150px;
    margin: 20;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 17px;
    color:#1e272e ;
    background-color: #f1c40f;
    border-color:#ecf0f1;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bolder;


}
#submit:hover{
    background-color:#f39c12 ;
}

form{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;    

}
#email{

    width: 400px;
    height: 30px;

}


#header-img{
    max-width: 4.5%;
    height:auto;
    margin-left: 20px;

}
nav{
    display: flex;
    float: left;
    justify-items: flex-start;
    margin: 140;

}    
.nav-link{
    margin-left: 80;
    margin-right: 20;
}
.middle-content{
    width: 800px;
    height: auto;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: auto;

    padding-top: 50;




}







.icon{
    max-width: 10%;
    height: auto;



}
.text-align{
    margin: 30;
}







#video{
    max-width: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 100;
}
#youtube-video{
    display: flex;
}


.price-css{
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color:#c5dff7;
    border: 1px solid rgb(70, 69, 69);
    border-radius: 3px;

}


#price-container{
    width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
    margin: auto;

}
#price-control{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 90;
}
#price1{
    margin-right: 90;
    background-color: #ecf0f1;


}
#price2{
    background-color: #ecf0f1;

}
.shadow{
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #f1c40f;
    border-bottom: #f1d667 solid;
}
.price-text{
    text-align: center;
}

footer{

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: auto;

}
#copyright{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: oblique;
}

#footer-parent{
    color:  #ecf0f1 ;






    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    border-radius: 2px;

}
#terms{
    margin-right: 35;
}


button{
    margin-top: 30;
    width: 150px;
    height: 28px;
    background-color: #f1c40f;
    border-color:#ecf0f1;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 17px;
    color:#1e272e ;

}
a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #ecf0f1;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

the problem is when I put my code in codepen the element of my page appears without any space between the elements

URL for the problem: https://codepen.io/mustafa-adnan1997/pen/rNxeyyL

can you help me know what my problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you did not add a **unit** such as `px` to the CSS code. Try changing for example `margin: 20;` to `margin: 20px;`

Comment: The term of art is *unit* rather than *measurement type*, but still a good answer :).